# Provided WS-Addressing to SOAP message with CustomBinding

Tags: c#, soap, wcf-binding

I need to provided the "Action" and "To" elements from WS-Addressing (namespace: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing) to a SOAP message using a CustomBinding. I want something like that:

```
var binding = new CustomBinding { Name = bindingName };
binding.Elements.Add(new WsAddressingBindingElement
{
     Action = "...",
     To = "...",
});
```

Is there any way to do it.